# Confused by AWS DynamoDB with UserID

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS platform. I am trying to build a backend for a mobile app using AWS lambda, API gateway and DynamoDB using Facebook Authentication of  AWS Cognito for my app.

A user are able to logged in to app and data should saved in a table with UserID (which I get from Cognito), data1, data2, data3. This only belongs to this. Let's say those are user's activities.

Again when he login to app next time, he should be able to see all his entered data.

I was looking for the example of it, I found this link which is about fine grained access control where the table is Partitioned with a particular user and permission.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/dynamodb-on-mobile-part-5-fine-grained-access-control/

That doesn't sound right. In a regular RDBMS centered app, the application connects to the database using a specific user in a connection string. User specific data is returned to the user using a query that is constructed on the fly with "username = user_id".

Is this above link talking about something different?

I am confused.

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the article you linked is discussing allowing an app to access DynamoDB directly, by calling the AWS API directly instead of going through a backend application layer. It is using variables in the IAM policy to only allow a user to execute queries against the table that contain their ID as the primary key.

In your case the AWS Lambda function is your backend application layer. You could simply assign an IAM role to the Lambda function that allows it to query all records in the DynamoDB table, and build queries in the Lambda function using the UserID as the query key.